# Can't place blocks in modded creative mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I've recently been having difficulty in Minecraft. It's a modded creative, but sometimes, I can break blocks but not place them in creative mode. I switched over to a server that used the same mod I was playing and I couldn't place on there either.

When I play a non-modded game (typically 1.8.8) it works fine.

My internet is at 5 full bars (4 sometimes) and runs very smoothly. It also mostly only occurs after I make a new world and play on it shortly after making it (and, I have a load of worlds.)

EDIT: It now happens mid-game too. It happened with any mod I used, same or different, and does not occur in vanilla Minecraft. I use Forge 1.7.10.

Comment: Even if this is not a duplicate, it is highly unclear. The mod seems to cause the issue, but you are not even telling us which mod it is, and which version of the game (& mod) you are playing on. When you start an unmodded game on the same Minecraft version as your modded game, does the problem exist?

Comment: Edited above, and explained, and for a bit more detail, "I can break blocks but not place them in creative mode". It happens even in survival.  It also does not let me interact with anything, from spawn eggs, opening dispensers, ect. and basicly things that have to use the right key...

Comment: Basically, what you are saying is that when you are running Forge, your Right Mouse Button randomly stops working? That's a largely different question. Have you tried a blank Forge version? As in, just install Forge, include no mods at all, and try.